# In Python3, how to create a any level nested list which is equal in numeric but independent from other any level nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, nested

There is a project which I have to implement in python3. However I get stuck with a problem as below.

For the single level list like `l=[a,b,c]`, a,b,c are not iterable, if want to copy it in content, only use `n=l[:]`, However, when there is multi-level nested, whose a,b,c are iterable, even if 'pointer' a,b,c are new variable, but their reference are still point at the original position.

a unknown level nested list was transfer as an argument to a function. there will be some operation inside this function to the argument, but I don't want to make any change to the original list object in this function's caller. So i want to copy this object in to a new object.

To make it easy to read, I try some method I wish it can work as below:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[a,a,a]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> a[1]=10
>>> b
[[1, 10, 3], [1, 10, 3], [1, 10, 3]]
>>> c=list(b)
>>> c
[[1, 10, 3], [1, 10, 3], [1, 10, 3]]
>>> a[1]=20
>>> c
[[1, 20, 3], [1, 20, 3], [1, 20, 3]]
>>> d=b[:][:]
>>> d
[[1, 20, 3], [1, 20, 3], [1, 20, 3]]
>>> a[1]=30
>>> c
[[1, 30, 3], [1, 30, 3], [1, 30, 3]]
>>> d
[[1, 30, 3], [1, 30, 3], [1, 30, 3]]
```

But all attempt failed.

Are there anyone who have a brief and efficient way to create a new equal but independent object?

Comment: If you need multidimensional arrays of numbers, [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is vastly superior to anything you could do with lists.

Comment: @user2357112 the data structure I need is more unregulated. Instead of multidimensional array. Furthermore, the elements in this structure are not always number but various of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import copy
my_copy = copy.deepcopy(obj_passed_to_me)
```

Comment: Looking at the question, he may have just added in the integers to simplify his example.  If the array is of objects this is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest thing would be the following:

`b=[list(a),list(a),list(a)]`

The problem in your example is that by doing `[a,a,a]` you do not create **new** object.

Comment: That was just a sample to describe the problem. In fact, in the project a can be a very complicated nested list.

Comment: @user9364854 in that case use `deepcopy()` as @chrisz suggested.